# Soft video encoder for M4

Tags: video

Video encoding is a computationally heavy task. I like to ask, are the video specs that can be managed with a ARM M4 (STM32F4 type CPU) type CPU? Perhaps low frame rate (10fps) and only VGA quality.

Comment: Perhaps this question would do better at stackOverflow.com

Comment: @Rocketmagnet you may be right.. I also asked at dsp stack exchange.

Comment: This is going to depend on your exact codec algorithm and how much it's optimised. For practical purposes get a SOC with built-in video encoding support. Where is your video from?

Comment: @Ktc: it is poor form to post on two stack exchange sites.

Comment: With only 192 kB of on-chip ram it would require external ram just to store a 640x480x8bpp uncompressed image, which negates some of the appeal of these devices.

Comment: cross posting is considered abuse.

Comment: @ChrisStratton not really true. The nice ICs with encoders goes for 20+$. (TI Davinci series is a good example) The STM32 can be as low as 4-5$ with added RAM 6$. A low CPU encoder would enable some apps that are cost effective and not possible with 20$ CPUs.

Comment: @Kortuk arguable.. We are discussing different parts of the problem in both places. Here the system issues (memory, CPU capability etc), there the algo side Mpeg vs. other etc. You guys are so anal on small things. I am not so sure best way to moderate this.

Comment: @ktc, On stackexchange cross posting has the result of closing all of the associated questions.

Answer (score -1):

THere seems to be a lot of info on QVGA and not so much on VGA
http://www.codeforge.com/s/0/STM32F4-VGA-320x200-256-colors-keil

[**But this brochure has some info**](http://www.emcu.it/SILICA-STDay-2011/STpresentation/STM32F4_tech_details_V1-0_Silica_1hour.pdf)

With a 48MHz PIXCLK and 8-bit parallel input data interface it is possible to receive:
 - up to 15fps uncompressed data stream in SXGA resolution(1280x1024) with 16-bit per pixel
 - up to 30fps uncompressed data stream in VGA resolution (640x480)with 16-bit per pixel
[image]

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question.